# Could not find libhdf5.so.6 during CREATE EXTENSION postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i tried to create extension for postgis in postgresql 9.5. I've already follow from [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html)

But it doesn't work like i expected. I got error `ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.5/lib/rtpostgis-2.2.so": libhdf5.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when i execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`

I have had install this on my other machine which run ubuntu. But this machine using centos 6. am i missing something? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the package you need is `hdf5`

There have been a fair number of problems reported with this library (a quick google search is helpful), but you may try making sure you can find `libhdf5.so.6` on your system and if not reinstalling the rpm.

If that doesn't work, build the library from source or find an alternate version for download?